# SQL Query To Set Rows as Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Since I am using SQL Server 2000 and don't have the luxury of SQL Server 2005's pivot tables, I need some help on creating a query.

Below find some sample data.

```
TBLProduct
ProductID   ProductName
1           Jacket
2           Blazer
3           Chaleco

TBLFactors
FactorID    FactorName
1           Length
2           Threading
3           Wool
4       Cotton

TBLFactorInspect
ID  ProductID   FactorID    FactorValue
1   1           1           5.00
2   1           2           5.55
3   2           2           6.33
4   2           3           3.66
5   2           4           1.05
```

I need help on a query that would output the data to this:

```
ProductID   ProductName Length  Threading   Wool    Cotton
1           Jacket      5.00    5.55        -       -
2           Blazer      -       6.33        3.66    1.05
3           Chaleco     -       -           -       -
```

I think I would also need another query such that, for example, only the ProductID = 1 was queried, the resulting data would return the factor as columns with which a value has been defined, i.e.:

```
ProductID   ProductName Length  Threading
1           Jacket      5.00    5.55
```

Any suggestions highly appreciated. Thanks.

Update:
If a stored procedure would be the best answer to achieve this, then I don't have any issues with that as I seem to think that SQL Server 2K's limitations on creating pivots is the main road block here.

I am trying to work on a Dynamic SQL in a Stored Proc solution but I ain't getting far on the dynamic column - value mapping.

Comment: you can use cursors to do this....

Comment: Is this something that you can handle in the front-end? That's really where display type issues are best handled whenever possible.

Comment: Cursors?  ARGH!  Who suggests cursors???

Comment: By the way, I think there is some kind of new license for SQL Server where you basically rent it rather than purchasing it.  I know my company found this to be MUCH more economical.  Upgrading to 2008 should not be that expensive anymore with this new option.

Comment: A stored procedure may be an option, but I am still having some issues being able to define the query when the factor table's data grows.

Comment: Why do you think a stored procedure is different from a query? A stored procedure just runs a query (and, potentially, other commands).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a SQL Server 2000 instance handy to try, but see if this gets you anywhere. I'm a little surprised about the requirement to include columns conditionally - let's hope the application is built to handle the case where columns suddenly appear and disappear depending on the parameters and the changing data in the TBLFactorInspect table.

```
USE [tempdb];
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
```

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TBLProduct
(
    ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY, ProductName NVARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT dbo.TBLProduct(ProductID, ProductName)
SELECT 1, 'Jacket'
UNION SELECT 2, 'Blazer'
UNION SELECT 3, 'Chaleco';

CREATE TABLE dbo.TBLFactors
(
    FactorID INT PRIMARY KEY, FactorName NVARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT dbo.TBLFactors(FactorID, FactorName)
SELECT 1, 'Length'
UNION SELECT 2, 'Threading'
UNION SELECT 3, 'Wool'
UNION SELECT 4, 'Cotton';

CREATE TABLE dbo.TBLFactorInspect
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY, ProductID INT,
    FactorID INT, FactorValue DECIMAL(5,2)
);

INSERT dbo.TBLFactorInspect(ID, ProductID, FactorID, FactorValue)
SELECT 1,1,1,5.00 UNION SELECT 2,1,2,5.55
UNION SELECT 3,2,2,6.33 UNION SELECT 4,2,3,3.66
UNION SELECT 5,2,4,1.05;
GO
```

Now some code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetProductPivot
    @ProductID INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);
    SET @sql = N'';

    SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
        ' + QUOTENAME(FactorName) 
        + ' = MAX(CASE WHEN d.FactorID = ' 
        + RTRIM(FactorID) + ' THEN d.FactorValue END),'
    FROM
    (
        SELECT f.FactorID, f.FactorName
        FROM dbo.TBLFactorInspect AS d
        INNER JOIN dbo.TBLFactors AS f
        ON f.FactorID = d.FactorID
        WHERE (d.ProductID = @ProductID OR @ProductID IS NULL)
        GROUP BY f.FactorID, f.FactorName
    ) AS f
    ORDER BY f.FactorID;

    IF @sql = N''
    BEGIN
        SELECT ProductID, ProductName, 
            Result = 'No data in TBLFactorInspect'
            FROM dbo.TBLProduct
            WHERE ProductID = COALESCE(@ProductID, ProductID);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = N'SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, ' + 
            LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql)-1) + '
                FROM dbo.TBLProduct AS p
                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TBLFactorInspect AS d
                ON p.ProductID = d.ProductID
                ' + CASE WHEN @ProductID IS NOT NULL THEN 
                ' WHERE p.ProductID = ' + RTRIM(@ProductID) ELSE '' END + '
                GROUP BY p.ProductID, p.ProductName
                ORDER BY p.ProductID;';

        EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql;
    END
END
GO
```

Some proof that it works with no parameters or specific productIDs:

```
EXEC dbo.GetProductPivot;
EXEC dbo.GetProductPivot @ProductID = 1;
EXEC dbo.GetProductPivot @ProductID = 2;
EXEC dbo.GetProductPivot @ProductID = 3;
GO
```

And now let's add a new factor and prove that it continues to work:

```
INSERT dbo.TBLFactors(FactorID, FactorName)
    SELECT 5, 'Tubing';

INSERT dbo.TBLFactorInspect(ID, ProductID, FactorID, FactorValue)
SELECT 6,1,5,2.75;
GO
EXEC dbo.GetProductPivot;
EXEC dbo.GetProductPivot @ProductID = 1;
GO
```

Clean up:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.TBLProduct, dbo.TBLFactors, dbo.TBLFactorInspect;
GO
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.GetProductPivot;
GO
```

Comment: This SP only gets the MAX Factor due to the statement generated:

MAX(CASE WHEN d.FactorID = 4 THEN d.FactorValue END),

Comment: No, it was not supposed to be SUM. What I was referring to is that only the Factor named 'Cotton' is being displayed, instead of the other factors due to the MAX(Case....) statement. I am still figuring out how to be able to display the other columns and provide the corresponding value to each factor for every product. The data I displayed above is what I needed.

Comment: Sorry, new 2008+ coding habits die hard. Try changing `SELECT @sql +=` to `SELECT @sql = @sql +` ... I'll update the code.

Comment: Tried the updated code. I wonder why @sql value is this prior to running sp_executesql

SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, [Cotton] = MAX(CASE WHEN d.FactorID = RTRIM(FactorID) + THEN d.FactorValue END)
                FROM dbo.TBLProduct AS p
                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TBLFactorInspect AS d
                ON p.ProductID = d.ProductID
                
                GROUP BY p.ProductID, p.ProductName
                ORDER BY p.ProductID;

Comment: Try now, but I suspect you have changed the code I've used because (a) your result doesn't make sense unless you've moved some apostrophes around and (b) the previous version of the proc wouldn't even compile on SQL Server 2005 (Msg 139) again because of SQL 2008+ habits.

Comment: Great, my only warning is that in SQL Server 2000 you're limited to 4000 characters, so if you start going crazy adding lots of factors, you're going to hit an upper limit pretty quickly on the length of the dynamic SQL string. You know that 2000 is way past end of life support, right?

Answer (score 1):

Without dynamic SQL, you need to be explicit about which columns you'll end up with.  (In SQL Server 2000 you can only Pivot if you already know what the column names, etc, are going to be.  If you need a dynamic number of columns, with dynamic names, SQL Server 2000 can't do this without coding Dynamic SQL)

Additionally, as per a comment, denormalising data is often best done in a GUI, not on the databse itself.

But this should do what you're asking for...

```
SELECT
  tblProduct.ProductID,
  tblProduct.ProductName,
  MAX(CASE WHEN tblFactorInspect.FactorID = 1 THEN tblFactorInspect.FactorValue END) AS Length,
  MAX(CASE WHEN tblFactorInspect.FactorID = 2 THEN tblFactorInspect.FactorValue END) AS Threading,
  MAX(CASE WHEN tblFactorInspect.FactorID = 3 THEN tblFactorInspect.FactorValue END) AS Wool,
  MAX(CASE WHEN tblFactorInspect.FactorID = 4 THEN tblFactorInspect.FactorValue END) AS Cotton
FROM
  tblProduct
LEFT JOIN
  tblFactorInspect
    ON  tblFactorInspect.ProductID = tblProduct.ProductID
GROUP BY
  tblProduct.ProductID,
  tblProduct.ProductName
```

Adding `WHERE tblProduct.ProductID = 1` will also give what you were asking for as the second half of your question.

Comment: -1: Column number will be dynamically generated, based on the rows from TBLFactors. You cannot use CASE statements here.

Comment: As per the answer, I state that without dynamic sql (and in SQL Server 2000) you can't get a dynamic number of columns.  For a fixed (and known) set-up, the above solution does indeed work to pivote/de-normalise the data.  (Answer updated to be even more explicit that you can't get a dynamic number of columns without dynamic sql, in sql server 2000)

Comment: Also, for the second query, when tblProduct.ProductID = 1, he will need only 2 columns, not the whole 4 of them.

Comment: Also, here without dynamic SQL, cursors are a feasible solution.

Comment: Please post your cursor based solution to generate the dynamically generated columns, so that we can vote on it for you.

Comment: This is not about voting (up/down). We try to find answers to a specific question.

Comment: Agreed, but I don't know how to generate the dynamic columns, even with a cursor, and the OP may be interested in your solution.

Comment: @Parkyprg: Indeed, how can you generate dynamic columns with a cursor? Unless you meant using a cursor *and* dynamic SQL.

Comment: If a Stored Proc would be a more feasible solution to this, kindly post it as well. Thanks,

Comment: Removed my suggestion as the problem was a little different and also assumed SQL 2005+...

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to use left joins like this:  (Everything is explicit, but that works with a finite number of rows in tblFactors)

```
SELECT
  tblProduct.ProductID,
  tblProduct.ProductName,
  ISNULL(tblLength.FactorValue, '-') AS [Length],
  ISNULL(tblThreading.FactorValue, '-') AS Threading,
  ISNULL(tblWool.FactorValue, '-') AS Wool,
  ISNULL(tblCotton.FactorValue, '-') AS Cotton
FROM
  tblProduct
LEFT JOIN tblFactorInspect tblLength
    ON  tblLength.ProductID = tblProduct.ProductID AND FactorID = 1
LEFT JOIN tblFactorInspect tblThreading
    ON  tblThreading.ProductID = tblProduct.ProductID AND FactorID = 2
LEFT JOIN tblFactorInspect tblWool
    ON  tblWool.ProductID = tblProduct.ProductID AND FactorID = 3
LEFT JOIN tblFactorInspect tblCotton
    ON  tblCotton.ProductID = tblProduct.ProductID AND FactorID = 4
```

Comment: +1 : Does involve more joins (and *usually* lower performance) than the GROUP BY alternative, but it **is** much more intuitive for other people to read and understand.  And that can't be underestimated in terms of maintainability.

Comment: I quite get this query, but what if the table TBLFactors grows? Like for example, new factors are added and inspection values are also specified?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a dynamic query.  With SQL Server 2000, the PIVOT option is not available.

Comment: As in my answer, there is no single query, in a Stored Procedure or otherwise, that can solve your requirement.  You requre Dynamic SQL; code that writes a SQL Query depending on the contents of you tblFactors table.  See the comment from Aaron Bertrand on my answer.